# Why TCP Socket send() gives failed error code 58?

Tags: sockets, error-handling, tcp, port, send

There are two operations between two device. Two of them use same port. One of them leaves to port and another uses. We can say these operations X and Y, respectively. When i start to X operation, there is no problem and it is finished successfully. Then i start to Y operation, it is also successful. However then i want to do X operation, there is problem in send() command. The error code is 58.

Do you have any idea why this error occurs ? And is there any suggestion about this condition ?

Comment: What does strerror(58) return?

Comment: With no code (and it not even being clear what language you are using), it's very hard to help you. Are commands before the `send` scrupulously checked for errors? Is it possible there's an earlier error that the code is not detecting? What does error code 58 mean on your platform?